# jQuery Validate Cannot call method 'call' of undefined

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-validate

This errors driving me nuts, everything seems to be in order, but hopefully I'm missing something simple.

Code in my aspx

```
        $('#myForm').validate({
            rules: {
                'ctl00$SecondaryPlaceHolder$txPayloadDate': {
                    required: true,
                    date: true
                },
                'ctl00$SecondaryPlaceHolder$ddlMapPlat': {
                    required: true
                },
                'ctl00$SecondaryPlaceHolder$txtBlock': {
                    maxLength: 3
                },
                'ctl00$SecondaryPlaceHolder$txtLeakNumber': {
                    number: true,
                    maxLength: 27
                },
                'ctl00$SecondaryPlaceHolder$txtHouseNumber': {
                    required: true,
                    maxLength: 10,
                },
                'ctl00$SecondaryPlaceHolder$txtStreet': {
                    required: true,
                    maxLength: 100
                },
                'ctl00$SecondaryPlaceHolder$txtCity': {
                    required: true,
                    maxLength: 50
                },
                'ctl00$SecondaryPlaceHolder$txtReading': {
                    isPositiveInteger: true,
                    maxLength: 100
                },
                'ctl00$SecondaryPlaceHolder$ddlInfoCodes': {
                    existsWithLowReading: true
                },
                'ctl00$SecondaryPlaceHolder$txtLocationRemarks': {
                    maxLength: 500
                },
                'txtGrade2RequestedRepairDate': {
                    date: true
                },
                'ctl00$SecondaryPlaceHolder$ddlEquipment': {
                    required: true
                }
            }
        });
```

custom validations

```
$.validator.addMethod("isPositiveInteger",
    function (value, element) {
        if($.trim(value) !== '')
            return /^\d+$/.test(value);
        return true;
    },
    "Must be a valid integer."
);


$.validator.addMethod("existsWithLowReading",
    function (value, element) {
        if (parseFloat($('#SecondaryPlaceHolder_txtReading').val() <= 2) && value.length < 1) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    },
    "Info Code required if Reading % is less than three."
);
```

Basically the issue is outside of the custom validations, but I threw them up here anyways...the form is validating fine when submitting, but there are a few 'house number' and 'street' that throw this error when trying to fill them in.

For example, I submit the form with an empty street number, the validation works, but when I fill in the input, on blur this error is being thrown.

The error is in jquery.validate here on the `var rule = { method: method, parameters: rules[method] }` line:

```
 check: function (element) {
            element = this.validationTargetFor(this.clean(element));

            var rules = $(element).rules();
            var dependencyMismatch = false;
            var val = this.elementValue(element);
            var result;

            for (var method in rules) {
                var rule = { method: method, parameters: rules[method] };
                try {

                    result = $.validator.methods[method].call(this, val, element, rule.parameters);

                    // if a method indicates that the field is optional and therefore valid,
                    // don't mark it as valid when there are no other rules
                    if (result === "dependency-mismatch") {
                        dependencyMismatch = true;
                        continue;
                    }
                    dependencyMismatch = false;

                    if (result === "pending") {
                        this.toHide = this.toHide.not(this.errorsFor(element));
                        return;
                    }

                    if (!result) {
                        this.formatAndAdd(element, rule);
                        return false;
                    }
                } catch (e) {
                    if (this.settings.debug && window.console) {
                        console.log("exception occured when checking element " + element.id + ", check the '" + rule.method + "' method", e);
                    }
                    throw e;
                }
            }
```

Thanks in advance for any pointers

Comment: For sting its better to use indexOf instead of ===

Comment: if (result.indexOf("dependency-mismatch") > -1)

Comment: Also change your selectors by removing the ContentPlace holders...  Something like this instead of 'ctl00$SecondaryPlaceHolder$txPayloadDate' do this   '[id*=txPayloadDate]'

Comment: To the first comments, that's jquery-validation code, can't do anything about that...will change my field names, but I found the real problem

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Dumb typo on my part was the culprit

maxLength is not camel cased, and should be maxlength

Although equalTo is camel cased...seems inconsistant, but glad I figured it out

Comment: Yuk! Plugin author should be ceremonially defrocked.